# Proving That Two Paths of Different Lengths Are Adjoined

Tags: special-functions, analytic-geometry

In [the section on 'Adjoining Paths'](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Topology/Path_Connectedness#Adjoining_Paths) of its ['Topology'](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Topology/) book's [page on 'Path Connectedness,'](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Topology/Path_Connectedness) [WikiBooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Main_Page) shows that, for any topological space $X$ with members $a$, $b$, and $c$, the following…:

$$\forall a, b, c \in X: \left( \exists \vec{f_1}\colon \left[0, 1\right] \to X\right) \wedge \left(\exists \vec{f_2}\colon \left[0, 1\right] \to X\right) \Rightarrow \exists \vec{f}\!\left(t\right) = \begin{cases}\vec{f_1}\!\!\left(2t\right)\!, & t \in \left[0, ^{1}\!\!/_{2}\right] \\ \vec{f_2}\!\left(2t-1\right)\!, & t \in \left[^{1}\!/_{2}, 1\right]\end{cases}$$

…holds true.  **It appears, however, that this only works when $\vec{f_1}\!\!\left(\right)$ and $\vec{f_2}\!\left(\right)$ describe paths of equal length.**  In particular, $\vec{f}\!\left(^{1}\!/_{2}\right) = \vec{f_1}\!\!\left(1\right) \neq \vec{f_2}\!\!\left(0\right)\,$ and $\,\vec{f}\!\left(1\right) \neq \vec{f_2}\!\!\left(1\right)\,$ when, for example, the path described by $\vec{f_1}$ is the path which results from visiting each of the points on the Euclidean line segment $\overline{P_1P_2}$ in turn, the path described by $\vec{f_2}$ is the path which results from visiting each of the points on the Euclidean line segment $\overline{P_2P_3}$ in turn, and $\overline{P_1P_2} = 2\overline{P_2P_3}$.  **Since joining these two line segments' path functions as described above does not work since they are not congruent, how would I go about writing a piecewise path function to describe the path formed by tracing out first $\overline{P_1P_2}$ and then, continuing on from $P_2$, $\overline{P_2P_3}$?**

Comment: Sorry, why did you write $\vec{f}\!\left(^{1}\!/_{2}\right) = \vec{f_1}\!\!\left(^{1}\!/_{2}\right)$? We have that $\vec{f}\!\left(^{1}\!/_{2}\right) = \vec{f_1}\!\!\left(1\right)$ by definition of $f$.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out!  I'll edit my question to fix that.

Comment: @HowDoIMath:  OK, it's been fixed!

Comment: @HowDoIMath:  Is the reason you asked because you're working on an answer for me?

Comment: I don't think I understand what the issue is. For instance, I don't understand why you write $\vec{f}\!\left(^{1}\!/_{2}\right) = \vec{f_1}\!\!\left(1\right) \neq \vec{f_2}\!\!\left(0\right)\,$ Is this a typo? The way I see it, the paths $f_1$ and $f_2$ are being chosen/constructed, such that $f_1(1)=f_2(0)$, so that the second path starts where the first path left off. This is also the reason why the function $f$ is well-defined at the point $t=1/2$. Does this clear anything up? @RandomDSdevel

Comment: @HowDoIMath:  Basically, what I need help doing is _finding_ some functions $\vec{f_1}\left(t\right)$ and $\vec{f_2}\left(t\right)$ that describe the paths traced out by some lines that _I've already been given_ such that $\vec{f}\left(^1/_2\right) = \vec{f_1}\left(1\right) = \vec{f_2}\left(1\right)$.  So, no:  that's not a typo, it's the error I got the first time I tried to write the path functions for two line segments that I _already know_ share an endpoint in common.  I'd give you my attempt at writing those path functions, but this is review for an independent-study calculus class.

Comment: And, yes, @HowDoIMath, I know that there shouldn't be that much space between my path functions' names and arguments, but I ran out of room to insert LaTeX `\!` commands.

Comment: @HowDoIMath:  Never mind; this question may be ill-formed.  You see, I realized that it might only be logical to ask if a topological space is, and _not_ if some paths _inside_ it are, path-connected.  Besides, any two paths inside a path-connected topological space are path-connected if they share an endpoint, and two-dimensional Euclidean space _is_ path-connected, so I've worked around this nasty little problem.